# cleverreach error Call to a member function

Tags: typo3

After sending the newsletter registration (with powermail form), you will get an error message:

```
Call to a member function isReceiverOfGroupAndActive() on null 

Error thrown in file
/html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/cleverreach/Classes/Powermail/Validator/OptinValidator.php in line 37.
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade the cleaverreach Extension to 0.1.5, they have added the new inject annotation